# Neo4j Complex Queries (DARK TV SERIES)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Java project with Neo4j that links the different characters in the Dark(Netflix) series.
I now have to create different "complex" queries in Cypher.
A complex query is defined by the fact that we don't know what kind of data will be returne, but I'm not sure I understand what that means.
Is there anyone who can give me an example of a complex query for my project?

Here is my Java Code :

```
package dao;

import domaine.Personnage;
import org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.*;
import org.neo4j.driver.Record;
import org.neo4j.driver.types.Node;

import java.util.List;

public class BDD {
    public static Session connect_db() {
        return GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687").session();
    }
    public static void import_base(Session bdd) {
        delete_all(bdd);
        List<Personnage> persos = Data.get_liste_personnages();
        //Create the SicMundus node
        bdd.run("CREATE (s:SicMundus {name: 'Sic Mundus Creatus Est'})");
        //Creation of the
        for (Personnage p : persos) {
            try {
                Result res = bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne) WHERE p.nom='" + p.getLastname() + "' AND p.prenom='" + p.getName() + "' RETURN p");
                bdd.run("MERGE (f:Famille {famille: $famille})", Values.parameters("famille", p.getLastname()));


                Value p1 = res.next().get("p");
                //verifie si l'année existe déjà
                Result res2 = bdd.run("MATCH (a:Annee) WHERE a.annee=" + p.getYears() + " RETURN a");
                Value a1 = res2.next().get("a");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //bdd.run("CREATE (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "', genre:'" + p.getGender() + "', aliases: '" + p.getAlias() + "',
                // marriedTo:'" + p.getMarried() + "', parentOf:'" + p.getParentOf() + "', childOf:'" + p.getParents() + "', siblings:'" + p.getSiblings() + "',
                // killedby:'" + p.getKilledBy() + "', sicMundus:'" + p.getSicMundus() + "'})");
                bdd.run("CREATE (p:Personne {nom: $name, genre: $gender, aliases: $aliases, lastname: $lastname})", Values.parameters("name", p.getName(), "gender",
                        p.getGender(), "aliases", p.getAlias(), "lastname", p.getLastname()));
                //Create the nodes for each year
                for (int i = 0; i < p.getYears().size(); i++) {
                    bdd.run("MERGE (a:Annee {annee: $annee})", Values.parameters("annee", p.getYears().get(i)));
                }
            }
        }
        for (Personnage p : persos){
            //match les personne avec leur famille via lastname seulement une fois
            bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom: $name, lastname: $lastname}), (f:Famille {famille: $famille}) MERGE (p)-[:FAMILY]->(f)",
                    Values.parameters("name", p.getName(), "lastname", p.getLastname(), "famille", p.getLastname()));

            //Match les personnes entre elles via leur attribut parentof
            if(p.hasParents()){
                for (int i = 0; i < p.getParents().size(); i++) {
                    bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (p2:Personne {nom:'" + p.getParents().get(i) + "'}) CREATE (p)-[:CHILDOF]->(p2)");
                }
            }
            if(p.hasKids()){
                for (int i = 0; i < p.getParentOf().size(); i++) {
                    bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (p2:Personne {nom:'" + p.getParentOf().get(i) + "'}) CREATE (p2)<-[:PARENTOF]-(p)");
                }
            }
            if(p.isMarried()){
                bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (p2:Personne {nom:'" + p.getMarried() + "'}) CREATE (p)-[:MARRIED]->(p2)");
            }
            //Match les personnes entre elles via leur attribut siblings
            if(p.hasSiblings()){
                for (int i = 0; i < p.getSiblings().size(); i++) {
                    bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (p2:Personne {nom:'" + p.getSiblings().get(i) + "'}) CREATE (p)-[:SIBLINGS]->(p2)");
                }
            }
            //Match les personnes entre elles via leur attribut killedby
            bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (p2:Personne {nom:'" + p.getKilledBy() + "'}) CREATE (p)-[:KILLEDBY]->(p2)");
            //Create sic mundus relations
            if(p.getSicMundus())
                bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (s:SicMundus) CREATE (p)-[:SICMUNDUS]->(s)");
            //match personnes et années
            for (int i = 0; i < p.getYears().size(); i++) {
                bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne {nom:'" + p.getName() + "'}), (a:Annee {annee:" + p.getYears().get(i) + "}) CREATE (p)-[:LIVEIN]->(a)");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void delete_all(Session bdd){
        bdd.run("match (a) -[r] -> () delete a, r");

        bdd.run("match (a) delete a");
    }


}
```

Here is the graph :

[Neo4j Dark Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GrUP.jpg)

Here is an exemple of a query i've made :

```
public static void afficher_personnes_saut(Session bdd){
Result res2 = bdd.run("MATCH (c:Personne)-[r:LIVEIN]->(y:Annee)\n" +
                "WITH c AS personne, y\n" +
                "ORDER BY y.annee\n" +
                "WITH personne, reverse(collect(y.annee)) AS annees\n" +
                "WITH personne, annees, range(0, size(annees)-1) AS is\n" +
                "WITH personne, annees, is, annees + (last(annees) - 33) AS isa\n" +
                "WITH personne, annees, reduce(total=0, n IN is | (total + toInteger((isa[n] - isa[n+1]) / 33 - 1))) AS sum\n" +
                "WHERE sum > 0\n" +
                "RETURN personne.nom AS nom, annees AS Annees");
        System.out.println("Liste des personnes ayant sauté des années de façon anormale :");
        //print les personnes ayant sauté des années
        while (res2.hasNext()){
            Record record = res2.next();
            System.out.println(record.get("nom").asString() + " : " + record.get("Annees").asList());
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
```

The problem is that I know what to expect from this query and don't understand the difference with a complex one.

Here is a query i've made and considered as "complex" :

```
public static Personnage getRelationsPersonne(Session bdd, String nom) {
        Result res = bdd.run("MATCH (p:Personne)-[r]->(x) WHERE p.nom = '" + nom + "' RETURN p, x, type(r)");
        Personnage perso = new Personnage(nom);
        while (res.hasNext()) {
            Record r = res.next();
            String type = r.get("type(r)").asString();
            switch (type) {
                case "FAMILY":
                    perso.addFamily(r.get("x").asNode().get("famille").asString());
                    break;
                case "PARENTOF":
                    perso.addKid(r.get("x").asNode().get("nom").asString());
                    break;
                case "LIVEIN":
                    perso.addYear(r.get("x").asNode().get("annee").asInt());
                    break;
                case "MARRIED":
                    perso.addSpouse(r.get("x").asNode().get("nom").asString());
                    break;
                case "CHILDOF":
                    perso.addParent(r.get("x").asNode().get("nom").asString());
                    break;
                case "KILLEDBY":
                    perso.addKiller(r.get("x").asNode().get("nom").asString());
                    break;
                case "SIBLINGS":
                    perso.addSibling(r.get("x").asNode().get("nom").asString());
                    break;
                case "SICMUNDUS":
                    perso.addSicMundus(r.get("x").asNode().get("nom").asString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        return perso;
    }
```

```
Personnage jonas = BDD.getRelationsPersonne(bdd, "Jonas Kahnwald");
        jonas.ToStringClean();
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        Personnage ulrich = BDD.getRelationsPersonne(bdd, "Ulrich Nielsen");
        ulrich.ToStringClean();
```

This allows me to get all the nodes to which a given character is connected (French):

[Code Printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9DmD.png)

I'm now having trouble creating functions similar to this one.

Comment: can you clarify what problem you are facing? As both a Neo4j employee and fan of the Dark series, I'd love to help :D

Comment: @fbiville 
I've edited the post for you with an example of a sample query I'd like to create. The goal is to justify the use of Neo4j compared to a classical relational database.
Tell me If it's clearer and anyway thx for ur help appreciate it :)

Comment: @error404 - the topic of graph vs relational is really not something that can be answered here (it's far too broad, opinion-based, and very specifically domain-based for your particular data model, query needs, 3rd-party tools, etc).

Comment: @DavidMakogon
I understand the complexity of the subject. I just wanted to illustrate the fact that the type of query I am supposed to produce must be not achievable from a relational database.